# Powershell - Substring and pivot of information

Tags: text-files, string-matching, powershell-4.0

**Disclaimer** - *complete amateur at powershell. I'm basically throwing myself into the deep end to try and learn, so please forgive my ignorance.*

Here is my challenge - I have information in txt file format as such (EMC Storage array layouts):

Tier Name:  Extreme Performance
Raid Type:  r_5
User Capacity (GBs):  4382.54
Consumed Capacity (GBs):  3923.65
Available Capacity (GBs):  458.89
Percent Subscribed:  89.53%
Data Targeted for Higher Tier (GBs):  0.00
Data Targeted for Lower Tier (GBs):  8.02

What I want to offer the storage team is a report on where their goodies are at. So looking to end up with this:

> Tier name                    Raid Type       UCap          ConCap        AvCap       %Sub     ...etc
>
> Extreme Performance  r_5                      4382.54    3923.65      458.89      89.53     ...

So it's a combo of, grabbing everything before the **":"** as the heading and after the **":"** to the CRLF as the data, and pivoting that into a table.

It gets better: there are more blocks of data like this in the txt file, separated by a CRLF, but using the same labels. So need to grab only the data from these and amend them to the table above.

I've gathered that perhaps I need to work a Get-Content and then manipulate the string with a -replace perhaps, but seems like Get-Content reads that first entry (Tier Name:) as a drive. Whoops.

Again, I'm keen to learn and welcome pointers. Been going at it for a few hours now...

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'm understanding, is that you have many blocks like the one you've shown us, and that each block has exactly 8 entries (not more, not less). Also, you want to create a **CSV file** (am I right?). if I'm right, try this code:

```
$f="$env:TMP\=in.txt"
gc $f | %{
    $csv="$env:TMP\=csv.CSV"
    clc $csv -ea Ignore
    ${#items}=8
    $o=[pscustomobject]@{}
}{
    $splitted=$_-split':'
    if($splitted){
        $o|Add-Member $splitted[0] $splitted[1]
        if(($o.psobject.properties.count|measure -sum).count -eq ${#items}){
            $o|epcsv $csv -Append
            $o=[pscustomobject]@{}
        }
    }
}{
    ipcsv $csv -Header 'Tier name','Raid Type','UCap','ConCap','AvCap','%Sub','Higher','Lower'|
        select -Skip 1|
        ft -AutoSize
}
```

Notice that `$f` is the file with all entries; `${#items}` is the number of items per block; `$csv` is the resulting **CSV file**; I replaced the CSV file headers ***just when displaying them***.

**Here's the output for a `$f` like below:**

```
Tier name                Raid Type UCap     ConCap   AvCap   %Sub    Higher Lower  
---------                --------- ----     ------   -----   ----    ------ -----  
 Extreme Performance1     r_5       4382.54  3923.65  458.89  89.53%  0.00   8.1   
 Extreme Performance12    r_5       4382.54  3923.65  458.89  89.53%  0.00   8.12  
 Extreme Performance123   r_5       4382.54  3923.65  458.89  89.53%  0.00   8.123 
 Extreme Performance1234  r_5       4382.54  3923.65  458.89  89.53%  0.00   8.1234
```

**Here's an example of `$f` file content:**

```
Tier Name: Extreme Performance1
Raid Type: r_5
User Capacity (GBs): 4382.54
Consumed Capacity (GBs): 3923.65
Available Capacity (GBs): 458.89
Percent Subscribed: 89.53%
Data Targeted for Higher Tier (GBs): 0.00
Data Targeted for Lower Tier (GBs): 8.1

Tier Name: Extreme Performance12
Raid Type: r_5
User Capacity (GBs): 4382.54
Consumed Capacity (GBs): 3923.65
Available Capacity (GBs): 458.89
Percent Subscribed: 89.53%
Data Targeted for Higher Tier (GBs): 0.00
Data Targeted for Lower Tier (GBs): 8.12

Tier Name: Extreme Performance123
Raid Type: r_5
User Capacity (GBs): 4382.54
Consumed Capacity (GBs): 3923.65
Available Capacity (GBs): 458.89
Percent Subscribed: 89.53%
Data Targeted for Higher Tier (GBs): 0.00
Data Targeted for Lower Tier (GBs): 8.123

Tier Name: Extreme Performance1234
Raid Type: r_5
User Capacity (GBs): 4382.54
Consumed Capacity (GBs): 3923.65
Available Capacity (GBs): 458.89
Percent Subscribed: 89.53%
Data Targeted for Higher Tier (GBs): 0.00
Data Targeted for Lower Tier (GBs): 8.1234
```

The blank lines may or may not exist.

Comment: Yes! This is what I require, most excellent. Though... mmm, think I need to hit the books hard to understand what it is you are doing... but keen to learn. Very much appreciated Sir.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one route you can take if you're not married to the idea of doing a table is to use the nifty ConvertFrom-StringData cmdlet, which will let you quickly import data in a Name = Value format.

To use that, all we have to do is replace the colons with an equals sign, which we can do like this.

```
#Setup $string
$string ="Tier Name: Extreme Performance
Raid Type: r_5
User Capacity (GBs): 4382.54
Consumed Capacity (GBs): 3923.65
Available Capacity (GBs): 458.89
Percent Subscribed: 89.53%
Data Targeted for Higher Tier (GBs): 0.00
Data Targeted for Lower Tier (GBs): 8.02"
```

I didn't have a file with this info, so I just loaded it right into memory in the above step.  For your purposes, just run `$string=Get-Content -Path .\PathToFile\File.txt` to import the content into $string.

Now we can call the universal -Replace operator to replace characters in a string/variable/object, with the following syntax.

```
$string -replace ":","="
```

Which gives us this result:

```
>Tier Name= Extreme Performance
Raid Type= r_5
User Capacity (GBs)= 4382.54
Consumed Capacity (GBs)= 3923.65
Available Capacity (GBs)= 458.89
Percent Subscribed= 89.53%
Data Targeted for Higher Tier (GBs)= 0.00
Data Targeted for Lower Tier (GBs)= 8.02
```

See that, it's in Name = Value format, precisely what we need for the ConvertFrom-StringData cmdlet.  We can now just pipe that right into our convert cmdlet to start working with the data!

```
$string -replace ":","=" | ConvertFrom-StringData | ft -AutoSize

Name                                Value              
----                                -----              
Tier Name                           Extreme Performance
Consumed Capacity (GBs)             3923.65            
Data Targeted for Higher Tier (GBs) 0.00               
Percent Subscribed                  89.53%             
Raid Type                           r_5                
Available Capacity (GBs)            458.89             
Data Targeted for Lower Tier (GBs)  8.02               
User Capacity (GBs)                 4382.54
```

I hope this gets you started on your way!

Comment: Thank you very much, this is actually useful for another thing I'm trying to also do! :)